# Is D-Cycloserine available on the market

Tags: psychiatry

The dextrorotary form of cycloserine has been suggested to be helpful in fear extinction by some studies. Is the drug available on the market for psychiatric use?

Comment: The wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloserine says that it is available on market as a prescription drug. However, as I can gather from this article, it is sold as an antibiotic and is a mix of L and D isomeres.

Comment: How do you know it is a mix of L and D isomers?

Comment: Ah, well, maybe I've been overly declarative with my statement about that, I should've said "I guess that it is a mix of..". And I think that it is a mix because there is no explicit mention about what isomeres are there in the anibiotic form. Usually in the absense of any other information this means that there are both. This guess is further amplified by the specific mention of the D-isomere form in psychiatric use, where they talk about it as of a more specific case than the drug availalbe as antibiotic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should go to Health.SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not to be used for prescription purposes.